# C++ is there a way to force invocation of base class method from overriding method?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, overloading, base-class

I was wondering if, in modern C++, there is a way to force invocation of base class method from the method that is currently overriding it.
Let's look at an example scenario like the following:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void initialize()
  {
    ... initialization stuff common to all subclasses ...
  }
};


class Derived
{
public:
  virtual void initialize() override
  {
    Base::initialize();  // !! I can forget to do this!

    ... initialization stuff specific to Derived class ...
  }
};
```

I wonder if there is a way to force (at compile time) the invocation of base method from derived method, in order to avoid to forget some important initialization stuff provided by base class.

A possible ugly solution, that I adopt now, is the following (a sort of basic usage of the *template method* design pattern):

```
class Base
{
public:
  void initialize() // note: this is not virtual
  {
    ... initialization stuff common to all subclasses ...
    
    this->_innerInitialize();
  }

protected:
  virtual void _innerInitialize() // actual virtual method to be overridden by subclasses
  {
  }
};


class Derived
{
  virtual void _innerInitialize() override
  {
    ... initialization stuff specific to Derived class ...
  }
};
```

Does modern C++ offers a more elegant way to enforce this mechanism? Thank you all in advance.

Edit: since a lot of people are focusing about the initialize() method, the question was more general, not just for initialization methods, although the separation of construction and initialization is sometimes useful (for example for wrapper objects that encapsulate OpenGL entities, where sometimes you have to delay the initialization to a moment where a valid OpenGL context is available).

Comment: Use constructors for initialization?

Comment: Make a non-virtual method in the baseclass that does all the common work, then call the virtual method from within your baseclass and implement in derived class. But @JasonLiam is not wrong, object initialization should be done from the baseclass. Derived classes will also call construtors of baseclasses for you.

Comment: in reply to Jason Liam: the initialize method is just and example, I could want to do the same also for other methods, not just for initialization.

Comment: Pepijn Kramer: that's the solution that I described in the second part of the question, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: There's nothing "ugly" about your proposed solution. That's the clean and the right way to do it in C++, modern or legacy. Inheritance, and everything else in C++ works the same way. Instead of attempting to make them do something else, the right approach is to figure out how to do what needs to be done in the manner that it works in C++.

Comment: The short answer is No. One possible approach is to change the class hierarchy to separate the uninitialized and initialized base type in two. You start with the uninitialized type and only gain access to an object of the initialized type once you call the appropriate function. Of course this works less with inheritance and more with composition

Comment: @AndreaBuzzelli The 2nd way is called the _Template Method_ design pattern, and well known,  and established. I don't see what's _"unelegant"_ with it.

Comment: You could do it without virtual methods too : https://onlinegdb.com/Zwof_BH6k

Comment: The best way is to avoid "construct then initialise".  Instead, delay instantiating the object until it can be constructed.   After all, the *purpose* of a constructor is initialising the object.     The approach of having a public non-virtual function can be used (but really should NOT for initialising an object) as `void initialize() {Base::innerInitialize(); this->innerInitialize();}`.   If you do that, ensure that `Base::innerInitialize()` can be safely called twice on one object, because there are high odds that someone overriding it will explicitly call the base version.

Comment: @PepijnKramer very interesting and educational solution! I never stop learning new cool things you can do with the power of templates! Thank you

Comment: @AndreaBuzzelli You're welcome. I find I write more and more of my code using templates, and less with inheritance (unless it is inheritance from a pure virtual base class).  All to increase unit testability too (inheritance is often misused to do code-reuse, and that's not what inheritance should be used for).